# Facade design pattern for inventory

Tags: design-patterns

I was wondering if someone could give me an example of how i could use the facade pattern in an inventory system. My inventory is coffee, bagles, and pizza

I did write a state classes for checking on an order and delivery..

I am not asking someone to write code i just need some simple classes with any implementation.

I just want to be able to order inventory, check if stock is low, check inventory, add, delete, inventory on hand..

does this sound reasonable to use the facade in an inventory?

```
productFacade Interface class

inventory class
bagel class implements inventory(adding,deleting, stock on hand)
pizza class implement inventory
coffee class implements inventory
```

Is it reasonable to use he facade pattern with an order?

```
orderfacade

order class(create order)
address class(for delivery of pizza, bagel,etc)
orderline
basket item
```

I am trying to force the facade pattern into my program.
my program already uses abstract factory for pizza creation. decorator for condiments on the coffee and bagel.

Comment: Tagging this `java` and `c++` and asking questions about design patterns is just mean. :(

Comment: The Fascade pattern is just a sub-system. So imagine you're an outside wanting to use your program. What functions should be made available to them so that they can use your implementation without needing to know how it works.

Comment: Just don't name your classes based on the pattern they are using. You may change some of the implementation details one day (and perhaps the design pattern it is using). If that happens, you now have a class name that no longer reflects what the class is doing.

Answer (score 6):

A facade's main purpose is to wrap a complex subsystem or set of objects/interfaces into a simpler one. Basically, it decouples a client from needing to know too many implementation details and/or about all the necessary dependencies and then delegates the work down to the subsystem for the client. Facades can even wrap other facades if certain parts of the subsytem itself is too complex.

As Alex mentioned, a good way to think of things, is pretend you're the client. You go to the shop and order a bagel and a coffee. As far as you're concerned, you should just need to ask the waiter (the facade) to get you a large double-double and a bagel with herb and garlic cream cheese. The waiter will then take care of the details, such as making the coffee, pouring the coffee, toasting your bagel and spreading the cream cheese. You could consider the toaster a facade as well. The waiter is only concerned with putting the bagel in and pushing the slider down. He doesn't need to know how the toaster converts the electrical current in order to heat the coils and toast the bagel.

So break your ordering logic into useful steps and then encapsulate the implementation details that the client should not need to know that the facade can do for the client (or delegate to something else).

Hope that helps. I'm on my way out the door so I don't have time for a code sample. Maybe later tonight if the question isn't already loaded with good answers.

Answer (score 1):

think about what needs to be done for you (client) to get a cup of coffee. in your facade, you would have something like

```
+ Coffee order (Size size)
```

and internally you would have something like

```
order (Size size)
{
   grindBeans (size)
   installFilter ()
   getCup...
etc, etc
   return coffee
}
```

in general, facade simplifies your interaction with the object.